# finding the behavior of a spectrum

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have 15 audio files that represent a machine sound with different burden, which I  want to analyse, for that I calculated the spectrum using the `pwelch` function, the result look like:[image: spectrum]
as you can see, there is no huge difference between them, but some frequency area, there is some linearity in the difference between them : [image: spectrum]

my question is how can I analyse the spectrum to get the relation  between the audio files.

I'm not asking for codes but only for methodes of how to do that

Comment: If i understand your question right, cross correlation should yield the wanted results.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but can you please explain how the cross correlation could help me to find the relation between the different file name

Comment: [Wikipedia: Cross-Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) 'In signal processing, cross-correlation is a measure of similarity of two waveforms as a function of a time-lag applied to one of them.' And as you are looking for similarity between the waveforms it should work. Obviously your timelag is a lag induced into your x-axis.

Comment: well the point isn't to find similarity but define the difference between them and this in frequency domain !

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to achieve eventually, but to get the difference between spectra I would just calculate the distances between the different spectra for every frequency. Like some kind of norm. E.g specify one spectrum as the reference. Than you will end up with 14 differences for each of the other spectra. And then you can compare how the energies of the spectra differ with respect to the reference in all frequencies. If this is not what you want, you maybe have to specify, what your goals are?

Comment: thanks @ImNt  for your answer, I've already did that . I want to find a relation between the spectrum and the burder on the machine !

Comment: You can still use cross-correlation to measure "dissimilarity".  You just have to interpret the results differently.  As an example, a cross correlation score of 0 yields that the signals **are entirely dissimilar**.  A score of 1 yields that the signals are **exactly the same**.  I would still recommend using cross-correlation just like The Minion suggested.  Here you can also ignore negative correlation as it would indicate a time reversal of your signal.  If I interpreted your problem right, negative correlation would not be useful and so consider only values that are positive or 0.